# Oracle query to turn rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to turn rows into columns, but the way I'm currently doing is very uneffective. I'd like to find a method to do this that's doesn't require me to turn every thing into a subquery. This is what I'm currently using:

```
select h.request_id, h.SAMPLES_DATE, h.SAMPLES_TIME, h.parent_area_name, h.area_name, h.point_name, h.oblastname,
unistr((select r.measured_result from lab_requests_requrements r where r.request_id=h.request_id and r.requirement_id = 51)) wr51,
unistr((select r.measured_result from lab_requests_requrements r where r.request_id=h.request_id and r.requirement_id = 131)) wr131,
unistr((select r.measured_result from lab_requests_requrements r where r.request_id=h.request_id and r.requirement_id = 143)) wr143
from lab_requests_head_view h
where h.water_type_id = 3 and h.water_type = 2
order by h.request_number
```

I've got more than 300 different requirements and I need to write a subquery for each one. Is there a way to just pivot these so it can be more dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to just pivot these so it can be more dynamic?

Yes, you can use Oracle `PIVOT`. It allows to make code shorter, but anyway you need to describe all your 300 columns.

```
select *
  from (select h.request_id, h.SAMPLES_DATE, h.SAMPLES_TIME, h.parent_area_name, 
               h.area_name, h.point_name, h.oblastname,r.requirement_id
          from lab_requests_head_view h
               left join lab_requests_requrements r on r.request_id = h.request_id
         where h.water_type_id = 3 and h.water_type = 2)
 pivot (max(r.measured_result) for requirement_id in (51, 131, 143))
 order by h.request_number
```

You have to write all desired `requirement_id` in the line `for requirement_id in (...)` and choose an aggregate function. I used `max`, because I don't know which fits best for you. If you have unique results in `r.measured_result`, it should be OK.

P. S. Pivot is available in Oracle 11.1 or later versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN` and `CASE` .

```
SELECT h.request_id,
         h.SAMPLES_DATE,
         h.SAMPLES_TIME,
         h.parent_area_name,
         h.area_name,
         h.point_name,
         h.oblastname,
         UNISTR (CASE WHEN r.request_id = 51 THEN r.request_id END) wr51,
         UNISTR (CASE WHEN r.request_id = 131 THEN r.request_id END) wr131,
         UNISTR (CASE WHEN r.request_id = 143 THEN r.request_id END) wr143
    FROM lab_requests_head_view h
         JOIN lab_requests_requrements r ON r.request_id = h.request_id
   WHERE h.water_type_id = 3 AND h.water_type = 2
ORDER BY h.request_number;
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this might help me. I'm trying to form a sort of matrix where some requests will have a result, some might not for each r.requirement_id I have, without having to list every single r.requirment_id.